# error range check //no se por qué//

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo un problema con el código, técnicamente falla al pasar los numeros del arraylist a las correspondientes variables long ,me da un error que no conozco out of bounds que no se de donde sale, si alguien me pudiese ayudar lo agradecería

**La salida es:**

> ```
> It worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: 9
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 35
> 8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:8
> It worked 2 and number2 is:8
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 33
> 8,8,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:88
> It worked 2 and number2 is:88
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 31
> 7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:887
> It worked 2 and number2 is:887
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 29
>     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
> 7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:8877
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(It worked 2 and number2 is:8877
> ArrayList.java:429)
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 27
> 6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
>     at algo3pruebas.Algo3pruebas.main(Algo3pruebas.java:45)
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:88776
> It worked 2 and number2 is:88776
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 25
> 6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:887766
> It worked 2 and number2 is:887766
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 23
> 6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: 96
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 22
> 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:8877665
> It worked 2 and number2 is:8877665
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 20
> 5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:88776655
> It worked 2 and number2 is:88776655
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 18
> 5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:887766555
> It worked 2 and number2 is:887766555
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 16
> 5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: 965
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 15
> 4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:8877665554
> It worked 2 and number2 is:8877665554
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 13
> 4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:88776655544
> It worked 2 and number2 is:88776655544
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 11
> 3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:887766555443
> It worked 2 and number2 is:887766555443
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 9
> 3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:8877665554433
> It worked 2 and number2 is:8877665554433
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 7
> 3,2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: 9653
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 6
> 2,2,2,1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:88776655544332
> It worked 2 and number2 is:88776655544332
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 4
> 2,1,1,1,
> It worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: 96532
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 3
> 1,1,1,
> It worked 1 and  number1 is:887766555443321
> It worked 2 and number2 is:887766555443321
> the arraylist is: 
> the size is : 1
> 1C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
> ```

**Y el código:**

```
public class Algo3pruebas {

/**
 * @param args the command  line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Algo3pruebas algorith = new Algo3pruebas();
    ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] numbers = {3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5};
    long number1 = 0;//number 1
    long number2 = 0;//number 2
    long numbers_nocouple = 0;//numbers without couple
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        arraylist.add(numbers[i]);
    }
    //bubble algorithm to order arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arraylist.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (arraylist.get(j) < arraylist.get(j + 1)) {
                int tmp = arraylist.get(j + 1);
                arraylist.set(j + 1, arraylist.get(j));
                arraylist.set(j, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    //to show arraylist
    /*for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(arraylist.get(i) + ",");
    }*/
    int tamaño = arraylist.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
        if (arraylist.get(0) == arraylist.get(1)) {

            number1 = 10 * number1 + arraylist.get(0);//introduce the number(which is in the position 0 of the arraylist) in number1
            System.out.println("\nIt worked 1 and  number1 is:" + number1);
            number2 = 10 * number2 + arraylist.get(1);//introduce the number(which is in the position 1 of the arraylist) in number2
            System.out.println("It worked 2 and number2 is:" + number2);
            arraylist.remove(0);//removes the number in the position 0 of the arraylist
            arraylist.remove(0);//removes the number in the position 0 of the arraylist which was in the position 1 before
            //to print arraylist
            System.out.println("the arraylist is: ");
            algorith.print(arraylist);
            //
        } else {
            numbers_nocouple = 10 * numbers_nocouple + arraylist.get(0);
            System.out.println("\nIt worked 3 and numbers_nocouple is: " + numbers_nocouple);
            arraylist.remove(0);
            //to print arraylist
            System.out.println("the arraylist is: ");
            algorith.print(arraylist);
            //
        }
    }
    /*System.out.println("number1 is: "+number1);
    System.out.println("number2 is: "+number2);*/
}

public void print(ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
    System.out.println("the size is : " + arraylist.size());
    if (arraylist.size() == 1) {
        System.out.print(arraylist.get(0));
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(arraylist.get(i) + ",");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Buenas Luis, Bienvenido a StackOverflow Español. El idioma oficial es el Español, así que, para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad deberías traducirla, sinó seguramente será cerrada.

Comment: Aunque la traduzcas, tu pregunta no es clara. Vas a tener que mejorar la calidad de la pregunta también.

Comment: puede agregar el error que te da

Answer (score 0):

Hola el error debe de ser este: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` y en tu caso pasa porque estas recorriendo un ciclo usando un for con tamaño definido y lo estas posteriormente acortando. 
Para ejemplificar:

```
int tamaño = arraylist.size();//En esta linea dices que el tamaño es 30 por ejemplo osea el tamaño que tenga pero supongamos que son 30.
```

Esta ciclo: `for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++)` va a recorrer esos 30 espacios
Y en el else del condicional estas haciendo un `arraylist.remove(0);` esto hará que el tamaño sea en mi ejemplo 30-1 = 29. Si lo ves el ciclo aún estará programado para recorrer los 30 espacios pero ya no existe uno de los espacios porque lo eliminaste.

Prueba e intenta la siguiente solución usa un Iterador como por ejemplo te escribo este pseudo código:

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = arraylist.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      int element = itr.next();
       if(....){
           ///algun codigo
       }else{
        .....
         itr.remove()
        ...
       }
    }
```

Nota: trata de postear todo en español incluso los comentarios del código. Suerte!

Comment: ok gracias , ya me di cuenta pero gracias de todos modos y si tenias razón era exactamente eso , se soluciona con un while nada más